# SMB2.0 won't mount using CIFS, works on smbclient

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

Since the recent disabling of SMB1, I've tried to update my mounts to use SMB2.

The top level mounts (\server\share$) work OK.

The subdirectory mounts, however,(\server\files\service\subfolder) no longer mount with the vers=2.0 option. I instead get the error message:

```
//fs01/files/Users/Nick /mnt/Nick   cifs    defaults,uid=1001,gid=1001,credentials=/etc/smb_auth,vers=2.0   0       0

mount error(38): Function not implemented
```

I can view the share using smbclient directly, with

```
smbclient -m SMB2 \\\\fs01\files\Users -D Nick -A /etc/smb_auth
```

but I cannot get it to work with mount.cifs or mount.

EDIT

I have now got it to work with:

```
//fs01/Users$/Nick /mnt/Nick   cifs   defaults,uid=1001,gid=1001,credentials=/etc/smb_auth,vers=2.0   0       0
```

Which is odd, as the top line worked fine with SMB1.0.

Comment: Please post the full text of your fstab or mount command; otherwise we are forced to guess at what you are trying to do.

Comment: Glad it worked out.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It's odd that it worked fine mounting the full DFS path with SMB1, but not with SMB2. Having to have Users$ created as a top-level hidden share isn't idea, but seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

I had to use Linux 4.11.0 on Xenial to get SMB2 and DFS to work with automount/cifs-utils (we're using MIT krb5 for auth). 4.10.0, 4.8.0 and 4.4.0 gave "Function not implemented" IIRC.

Comment: 4.13.0-18+ also works.

Comment: 4.15 does not work

Comment: Which 4.15 exactly? On which version of Ubuntu? DFS + automount + SMB 2.1 works on 5.0.0-16-generic / 18.04 and AFAICR worked on several 4.15.0 versions, at least.

Comment: Having used git bisect, I think this relates to the commit 4a367dc0443566f87d73f2cdb94703b0e1374315 "cifs: Add support for failover in cifs_mount()" which I'm investigating, in conjunction with our local set up.